# Transpose key -> value table (rows) into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, transpose

We have a metadata pair key value table where we store daily kpis on a similar format to:

```
+------+---------+-------------+------------+ 
| id   | key     | value       | last_update| 
+------+---------+-------------+------------+ 
|    1 | key1    | foo         | 2022-08-08 | 
|    2 | key2    | bar         | 2022-08-08 | 
|    3 | key4    | more        | 2022-08-08 | 
|    4 | key2    | galaxy      | 2022-08-07 | 
|    5 | key3    | foo         | 2022-08-06 | 
|    6 | key4    | other       | 2022-08-06 | 
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

Only changed data from previous value gets saved so not all keys get created every day. New keys can appear any time.

In order to represent some output charts, I am looking for query for MySQL that could transpose the values to a more "traditional" format of one per day for all the keys that exist that day.

```
+---------+----------+---------+--------+------------+
| key1    | key2     | key3    | key4   | date       |
+---------+----------+---------+--------+------------+
| foo     | bar      | NULL    | more   | 2022-08-08 |
| NULL    | galaxy   | NULL    | NULL   | 2022-08-07 |
| NULL    | NULL     | foo     | other  | 2022-08-06 |
+---------+----------+---------+--------+------------+
```

I've tried different approaches to insert records based on a

> select DISTINCT id from source table ORDER BY id

that was based on similar replies here in stackoverflow, but without success.

CLARIFICATION EDIT
Solutions using the keys themselces for the query are not valid as they are not fixed, and can change or be added. I want to know if any a key_reference table could be used with a row per each key used.

Comment: What if there are multiple records for the same key on the same date?

Comment: What happens when you get key5?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pivot table given your example:

```
SELECT
 MAX(CASE `key` WHEN 'key1' THEN `value` END) AS `key1`,
 MAX(CASE `key` WHEN 'key2' THEN `value` END) AS `key2`,
 MAX(CASE `key` WHEN 'key3' THEN `value` END) AS `key3`,
 MAX(CASE `key` WHEN 'key4' THEN `value` END) AS `key4`,
 last_update AS date
FROM `source table`
GROUP BY date;
```

You do need to know the distinct values for `key` to format the query.

One must assume there's only one value for a given key on a given date.

Comment: Probably needs `MAX` (or `MIN`) on the date column.

Comment: No -- that's the column I'm grouping by.

Answer (score 0):

I use `GROUP_CONCAT` to solve this kind of problem unles you want only the first or last value of the group. Showing all associated values is important to not missing any information.

```sql
SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `key` WHEN 'key1' THEN `value` END) AS `key1`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `key` WHEN 'key2' THEN `value` END) AS `key2`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `key` WHEN 'key3' THEN `value` END) AS `key3`,
 GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `key` WHEN 'key4' THEN `value` END) AS `key4`,
 last_update AS date
FROM `source table`
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: For MySQL, one would use GROUP_CONCAT(). STRING_AGG() is a Microsoft SQL Server function.

Comment: Thanks. I was using PG and did not aware of the DB this question was using.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **PREPARED STATEMENT** to generate the Query. In this case you can change the count of keys in your table without changing the query.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mycol SEPARATOR ',\n') into @cols FROM (
SELECT CONCAT( "GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `key` WHEN '", `key`, "' THEN `value` END) AS '", `key` ,"'" ) AS mycol
FROM keytab
GROUP BY `key`
ORDER BY `key` ) as mycols;

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT ",@cols, ", last_update AS 'date' FROM `keytab` GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date` DESC");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**SAMPLE**

**the table**

```
mysql> SELECT * from keytab;
+----+------+--------+-------------+
| id | key  | value  | last_update |
+----+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | key1 | foo    | 2022-08-08  |
|  2 | key2 | bar    | 2022-08-08  |
|  3 | key4 | more   | 2022-08-08  |
|  4 | key2 | galaxy | 2022-08-07  |
|  5 | key3 | foo    | 2022-08-06  |
|  6 | key4 | other  | 2022-08-06  |
+----+------+--------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**the query**

```
mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT ",@cols, ", last_update AS 'date' FROM `keytab` GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date` DESC");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+------+--------+------+-------+------------+
| key1 | key2   | key3 | key4  | date       |
+------+--------+------+-------+------------+
| foo  | bar    | NULL | more  | 2022-08-08 |
| NULL | galaxy | NULL | NULL  | 2022-08-07 |
| NULL | NULL   | foo  | other | 2022-08-06 |
+------+--------+------+-------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**add a key an try again**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO `keytab` (`id`, `key`, `value`, `last_update`)
    -> VALUES
    -> (7, 'key7', 'Hello', '2022-08-05'),
    -> (8, 'key9', 'Bernd', '2022-08-05');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(mycol SEPARATOR ',\n') into @cols FROM (
    -> SELECT CONCAT( "GROUP_CONCAT(CASE `key` WHEN '", `key`, "' THEN `value` END) AS '", `key` ,"'" ) AS mycol
    -> FROM keytab
    -> GROUP BY `key`
    -> ORDER BY `key` ) as mycols;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT ",@cols, ", last_update AS 'date' FROM `keytab` GROUP BY `date` ORDER BY `date` DESC");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| key1 | key2   | key3 | key4  | key7  | key9  | date       |
+------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| foo  | bar    | NULL | more  | NULL  | NULL  | 2022-08-08 |
| NULL | galaxy | NULL | NULL  | NULL  | NULL  | 2022-08-07 |
| NULL | NULL   | foo  | other | NULL  | NULL  | 2022-08-06 |
| NULL | NULL   | NULL | NULL  | Hello | Bernd | 2022-08-05 |
+------+--------+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```